# JQuery iterate through multiple items and remove the first child of every item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know it might be a little bit dumm but i am really struggling with simple things like the following problem. Here is an example of the code that i have. The problem will be explained after the code. So here it is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="image_item">
                <img src="someSource">
            </div>
            <div class="image_item">
                <img src="someSource">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="image_item">
                <img src="someSource">
            </div>
            <div class="image_item">
                <img src="someSource">
            </div>
            <div class="image_item">
                <img src="someSource">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i would like to do, is to keep every first item (image_item) of every div with the class "image" and remove the rest. Any idea how to achieve that? So far i got this but it removes everything accept the first one on the first div.

```
$('.first_only .immo_image').not(':first').remove();
```

I also tried to iterate through each element with the following code:

```
$('. image').each(function () {
   $('.image_item').not(':first').remove();
});
```

But it does the same with the other example. It removes everything except the first image on the first div.

Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: The first script won't do anything, the second throws a syntax error...

Comment: .not filters the selection you apply it to, so `not(':first')` will only ever remove the first element of whatever collection you have created there. And in your second example, you are looping over the individual `.image` elements (assuming the space in the selector is removed), but then inside that loop you are still selecting _all_ `.image_item` elements in the whole document. To avoid that, supply the current parent item as context: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).find(".image_item:not(:first)").remove();` to remove all except the first image.

```js
$(".image").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".image_item:not(:first)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource">
      </div>
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource">
      </div>
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource">
      </div>
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your particular document tree, this should work:

```
$('.image').each(function () {
   $(this).find('.image-item').slice(1).remove();
});
```

For each `.image`, find all `.image-item` inside it and remove all but the first one (in document order).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to explicitly loop through the `.image` elements. You can use a single selector incorporating the `:nth-child` selector (negated with `:not`) to `remove()` all the elements you require. Something like this:

```js
$('.image .image_item:not(:nth-child(1))').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource"> 1-1
      </div>
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource"> 1-2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource"> 2-1
      </div>
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource"> 2-2
      </div>
      <div class="image_item">
        <img src="someSource"> 2-3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `:first-child` here instead of `:nth-child(1)`:  `$('.image .image_item:not(:first-child)').remove();`.   I doubt there's any tangible differences.